# Black Hole rotation and acceleration

Tags: black-holes, angular-momentum, faster-than-light, singularities, hawking-radiation

I have been reading some about the black holes and the rotation about it, and have also heard about the fastest spinning black hole (NGC 1365), which as I understand, its rotation is 86% the speed of light, and is very wide in diameter. Hence, it strikes my interest about its increase in rotation speed.

As I understand about Angular Momentum, when an object which is spinning, and radius gets smaller, it will spin faster. Surely when the NGC 1365 radiates away by hawking radiation, it will get smaller and will reach light speed at a time, and when it gets smaller, it will go faster than light speed. Is this the case, since as I understand nothing can go faster than the speed of light. Furthermore, if this is the case, will the ergosphere of NGC 1365 accelerate whatever that gets in there over the speed of light and escape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. the black hole has energy, and rest mass, so it will never reach the speed of light
2. spinning speed, angular momentum has the same speed limit as any other in the universe, for particles with rest mass, they cannot go faster then speed of light (not even reach the speed of light)